# Show XML from XSLT transformation in JavaFX TextArea

Tags: java, xml, xslt, javafx

I'm trying to make an application in which I write text in XML format into a TextArea and applies an indent transformation (with XSLT), to finally show it in an out TextArea.

But what I only receive is the content of the XML elements like in the image:

[image]

My code in Java is the following:

```
public class Vista extends Application{

Label LIn;
TextArea TIn;

Label LOut;
TextArea TOut;

Button BTransform;

String xslt = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + 
            "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"> " + 
            "<xsl:output method=\"xml\" version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" indent=\"yes\"/> " + 
            "<xsl:copy-of select=\".\"/> " + 
            "</xsl:stylesheet>";

@Override
public void start(Stage StageInicial) throws Exception {

    StageInicial.setTitle("XML Indent");

    LIn = new Label("XML Entrada:");
    TIn = new TextArea();

    LOut = new Label("XML Salida:");
    TOut = new TextArea();

    BTransform = new Button("Indent XML!");

    BTransform.setOnAction(action -> {
        try {
            transformation();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    gridPane.add(LIn, 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(TIn, 0, 1);

    gridPane.add(LOut, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(TOut, 1, 1);

    gridPane.add(BTransform, 0, 3, 2, 2);

    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 1048, 720);
    StageInicial.setScene(scene);
    StageInicial.show();       

}

public void transformation() throws TransformerException{

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(TIn.getText());
    StringReader readerXSLT = new StringReader(xslt);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(readerXSLT));

    transformer.transform(
            new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader), 
            new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));

    TOut.setText(writer.toString());

}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How could I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an identity transformation then (with JAXP) either create a new Transformer without providing a stylesheet at all (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer--) or make sure the XSLT you provide is actually performing the copy, your code with a top level `"<xsl:copy-of select=\".\"/> "` should not even compile I think, you rather want `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`.